# Snap transform pivot inside of selection

Tags: transforms, snapping

I'm a Modo user trying out Blender 2.8. This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Make a selection and activate the Transform(Move) tool
2. Snap the transform pivot to one of the vertices in the selection
3. Make the the transform pivot to snap to grid(or other snapping options)

The following gif demonstrates this in Modo:

[image]

Here is a screenshot from Blender 2.8 where I've been trying with different snapping options and using the cursor. Unfortunately I've not been able to achieve the correct snapping.

[image]

Is this possible in Blender 2.8?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you have `Absolute Grid Snap` enabled in the snapping options at the top of the *3D View*.

[image: Absolute Grid Snap]

This will snap the pivot point of any selected vertices to the closest grid increment when they're moved. To achieve the desired behaviour with this option turned on, you must select all of the vertices that you wish to move, then make the top on the active vertex (as I have done in my screenshot). Following this you can change the *Pivot Point* options to be around the `Active Element` using this menu:

[image: Pivot Point Options]

Alternatively, I believe that you can disable `Absolute Grid Snap` and your selected vertices will always snap 1 increment away from their original locations, regardless of the pivot point (i.e. they won't always necessarily align to the grid).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at my computer right now, but I'm pretty sure I would...

1. Select vertices to move
2. Press G to grab them
3. Press X or Y once, to restrain movement to that axis
4. Hold down ctrl to snap to grids
5. Zoom in a bit to snap to smaller grid squares or out to snap to larger ones

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've tried this and it snaps the whole selection's center point to the grid. Which will make the first vertex overlap the grid(referring to the images I posted).